# Is there a LaTeX editor similar to ISPF of IBM mainframes?

Tags: editors

ISPF editor (the dinosaurs who have worked on mainframe know it well) has a lot of very useful (IMO) line commands which allows you to avoid selecting the code with the mouse in order to cut & paste, delete, move, shift, etc. lines.

For example, with `cc ... cc` (= copy a block of lines) and `a` (= after) or `b` (= before) you can copy some lines after or before another line.

Commands:

```
Command ===>                      Scroll ===> CSR

**************************** Top of Data *****************************

cc0010 Some text
000020 Again some text
cc0030 Some text again and again
a00040 which I like to put after this line

*************************** Bottom of Data ***************************
```

Result:

```
Command ===>                      Scroll ===> CSR

**************************** Top of Data *****************************

000040 which I like to put after this line
000010 Some text
000020 Again some text
000030 Some text again and again

*************************** Bottom of Data ***************************
```

With `r<n>` you can repeat a line n times (this could be useful for editing tables).

Command:

```
Command ===>                      Scroll ===> CSR

**************************** Top of Data *****************************

r30010 A & B \\

*************************** Bottom of Data ***************************
```

Result:

```
Command ===>                      Scroll ===> CSR

**************************** Top of Data *****************************

000010 A & B \\
000010 A & B \\
000010 A & B \\
000010 A & B \\

*************************** Bottom of Data ***************************
```

Googling around I've found [SPFLite](http://www.spflite.com/) but it doesn't seem to be able to highlight LaTeX command like even the simple Notepad++ can do.

Does anyone know if there is an ISPF-like editor which can also highlight LaTeX commands? (I'm working on Windows 10).

Comment: You might like the "Eastern Orthodox" style of editors - that were originally clones of Xedit (on VM rather than TSO  but similar to ISPF).  Have a look at [THE](http://hessling-editor.sourceforge.net/) or [X2](http://www.tangbu.com/x2main.shtml).

Comment: @Thruston I'll look at them, I'm happy to see there is someone who knows what TSO is, thank you!

Comment: In VIM you can hit `V` in normal mode to switch to visual mode.  Then you can select lines by browsing the code.  Using `d` you cut these lines and insert them back after the cursor with `p` or before the cursor with `P`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you, I'll look at VIM too, it surely has LaTeX syntax highlighting, I'll try to discover if it has the corresponding line commands of the main ISPF ones.

Comment: See also:  http://www.softpanorama.org/Articles/orthodox_editors.shtml

Comment: emacs of course:-)

Comment: Thank you, @DavidCarlisle! The choice is becoming difficult...

Comment: No the choice is easy, there is only one editor, do not listen to heretical voices:-)

Comment: i'm with @DavidCarlisle here, being an emacs bigot.  it does have a steep learning curve, but it has a good tutorial, and once the commands are in your fingers, the only time you have to touch a mouse is to move to a different window.  (i hate guis.)  users of other editors have their own preferences.  the best advice i can give is to take a look at all that have been suggested and choose the one that you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: Thank you @barbarabeeton, indeed, in choosing emacs, the learning curve is what scares me the most!

Comment: Any news here? What editor did you choose? Do you want to write a self answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B I didn't find an editor like ISPF, I ended up with Notepad++ with a Nppexec to compile (using arara). Emacs is very good but I am too accustomed to ctrl-c ctrl-v to copy-paste. I don't like Vim very much.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but wonder where op ended up? I'm a tso ispf user on Z and I have been using vim without any issue on Linux, I used vimtutor for basics then using a book called Mastering Vim and one called practical Vim. And to bend it magically you can use Vimscript(tutorial is called learn vimscript the hard way)... it's got latex plug-ins as well and is purely terminal based. You will also find it installed as default more then any other editor around, especially the older Vi version.
You can also look at the newer nvim which uses lua as opposed to vimscript(i am still gonna stick with Vim though not de used as yet about nvim)...

I am hoping it will serve me well as I am planning to make it my main Editor and next step is actually to learn Latex.

Good luck

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried Vim but I find it too complex. I ended up using Notepad++ with a Nppexec to compile with arara. It is very simple to use.